# Select the very first elem with class in the page

Tags: css, css-selectors

The problem is very simple:
I can't find a way to select (only with css) the very first elem in page with a specific class.

For example with this HTML code I'd like to select the first element with class `.elem`:

```css
.elem:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">elem that I'd like to select</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">Unfortunately, this elem is selected too</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>
```

The current behavior is like the js' `querySelectorAll` function but the expected behavior is the one of `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.elem:nth-of-type(1)') // Current behavior is like this
document.querySelector('.elem:nth-of-type(1)') // Expected behavior is like this
```

Are there CSS tricks that can do what I want?

**EDIT:**

In the real case, I don't know the HTML code. The only thing I know is: "I need to select the very first `.elem` in the page with CSS"

Comment: `.elem:first-child`?

Comment: _“Are there CSS tricks that can do what I want?”_ - No.

Comment: @Roy Same behavior that the exemple I wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `nth-of-type`, `first-child`, `last-child` and such is that it always starts the count from the parent.

So in your example you have two parents(the `.wrapper`) classes.

So without a specific selector like `.wrapper:first-child .elem:first-child` you won't be able to select it universally.

You need to know the layout of the page if you wish to do with with pure css so you can build in the paths to only select the first elem within your page.

I did some experiments with `*:first-child > .elem:first-child { border:5px solid red }` and `body > *:nth-of-type(1) .elem:nth-of-type(1)` and they looked promising, but all have caveats. where you still need to know the layout of the page. Double nested elemens, multiple layers nested elems next to eachother can all be valid for the css, so I discarded those options and rolled this answer back to my initial. The safest bet is one line of JavaScript.

Now solutions you could implement are twofold:

If you use something like php or node-js to generate your page, you could use a one time switch when rendering the page

```
$first = true;
foreach($listitem as $item) {
   $output[] = '<div class="elem';
   if($first) {
      $first = false;
      $output[] = ' first';
   }
   $output[] = '>elem</div>';
   } 
}
```

If you you are allowed to use one line of JavaScript you could use something like this:

```
document.querySelector('.elem').classList.add('ello');
```

But with pure CSS and not using a very specific path in the page to where the first elem class appears this becomes nigh impossible.

```js
document.querySelector('.elem').classList.add('first');
```

```css
.elem.first {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">elem that I'd like to select</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">Unfortunately, this elem is selected too</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.wrapper:first-child .elem:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">elem that I'd like to select</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">Unfortunately, this elem is selected too</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>
```

select with div select first div with wrapper class using pseudo:first-child

Answer (score 1):

Use the same selector on the `.wrapper` element as well. Or you can use parent of the wrapper element and use `:first-child` selector.

Also note that nth-of-type will work only if the tags match and not for the classes as other answers mention. If you always want to select the first element inside the first element then `body > :first-child > :first-child` will work for you.

```css
body > :first-child > :first-child {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.wrapper:nth-of-type(1) .elem:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.outer-wrapper>.wrapper2:first-child > .elem:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">elem that I'd like to select</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="elem">Unfortunately, this elem is selected too</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
  <div class="elem">elem</div>
</div>

<section class="outer-wrapper">

  <div class="wrapper2">
    <p class="elem">Can be selected if you knowonly the class name</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper2">
    <p class="elem">Dont worry this wont be affected</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
    <p class="elem">elem</p>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: It works with this very simple example but the real case is that I don't know the HTML code. I just want the very first `.elem` in the page.

Comment: Added another example. If you have the class, then you can select that element. You dont need the element type in this.

Comment: Added one more example, if you always want to choose the first-element. If you want to use any other element use **nth-child**

Answer (score 1):

Just seen your edit. In that case the option that will work is:

```
.wrapper:first-child .elem:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

The solution is already provided above by @Mohammed

Comment: You may take a look at my "EDIT" mention at the end of the post :)